# Determine root of graph by DFS

Tags: graph-theory

If given a finite simple directed graph $G=(V,E)$ and a vertex $v$, can one use a DFS on the graph and equate the return (or finish) value of $v$ with $2|V|$ to determine whether it is a root of the graph?

Here's my attempt at a proof:
(The DFS assigns $d(v)$ the value of $v$ when first visiting it and $f(v)$ when returning from it).

Let us assume $v$ is a root of $G$ and falsely assume that it's return value determined by the DFS is not $2|V|$. Therefore there exists a vertex $u$ such that $f(v)<f(u)$.
$v$ is a root therefore there exists a path from $v$ to $u$ therefore $vu$ is a tree edge or forward edge in $G$ and $d(v)<d(u)<f(u)<f(v)$ which contradicts $f(v)<f(u)$ and therefore $f(v)=2|V|$.

Is my logic sound here?

Comment: Are you assuming that the (undirected?) graph is connected?

Comment: No. If it was not connected then the return value would indeed be lower but then it wouldn't be a root.

Comment: The question was edited to reflect that $G$ is directed.